# Magento2 collection not get set

Tags: magento2, collection

I have added following code to change the collection. The issue is that when I print the sql query then I am getting correct result(in mysql ) but after that when I print getData on collection then the products are different.

- Can someone please guide me on it?

Thanks

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('fan_motor_height_blades', 'catalog_product_entity_varchar');
            
            $zeroPriceLast = new \Zend_Db_Expr("fan_motor_height_blades = 0.000000 ASC, fan_motor_height_blades  ASC");

            $collection->getSelect()->order($zeroPriceLast);

            //echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();die();
            echo '<pre>';print_r($collection->getData());die();
```

Comment: Are you updating for category list collection?

Comment: @S.P No just want to sort via filter

Comment: did you check with reset order?
 $collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER)->order($zeroPriceLast);

Comment: @S.P I tried this $zeroPriceLast = new \Zend_Db_Expr("`fan_motor_height_blades` = '0.000000' ASC, `fan_motor_height_blades`  ASC");
                 $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER)->order($zeroPriceLast);

Comment: Not working as needed

Answer (score 0):

> Did you try like this?

```
foreach($collection as $key => $value)
{
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($value->getData()); die;
}
```

Comment: That is taking too much time

Comment: It shouldn't take much time as we have already applied the die function. Only will be fetched single record? Might be something you are doing wrong in collection

Comment: Die is fine it stopped, but not sure on how to will this add 0 valued attribute at last